# Typescript type enforce on promise types

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch, typescript2.0

Happy new year :)

I'm having some difficulties understanding a typescript problem.

i'm trying to convert my js project into a ts one, since better type enforcement and easier for bugs catching

Now I have a type:

```
export interface APIErrorInfo {
  code: number,
  msg: string,
  status: number
}
```

And i'm calling fetch, which returns a promise as usual

```
  get(path: string) {
    this.signApiCall(path, "GET", null)
    return fetch("http://" + this.apiHost + path,
      {
        method: "GET",
        headers: this.headers
      }
    ).then(
      json => {
        return this.errorHandle(json)
      }
    )
  }
```

here I understand that json is "any" type, so in my errorHandle I have

```
  errorHandle(jsonPromise: any): Promise<APIErrorInfo> {
    let json = jsonPromise.json()
    if(jsonPromise.status >= 400) {
      return json.then(err => {throw qiniuErrorHandle(jsonPromise.status)})
    } else {
      return json
    }
  }


const qiniuErrorHandle = (code): APIErrorInfo => {
  switch(true) {
    case code === 111:
      return {msg: "blah1", code: APICode.StreamExists, status: HTTPStatus.BadRequest}
    case code === 222:
      return {msg: "blah2", code: APICode.StreamDoNotExist, status: HTTPStatus.BadRequest}
    case code === 333:
      return {msg: "blah3", code: APICode.StreamHasNoData, status: HTTPStatus.BadRequest}
    default:
      return {msg: "Unknown error", code: APICode.UnknownError, status: HTTPStatus.InternalError}
  }
}
```

It's all good except the return type here. I'm asking errorHandle to return a Promise only (which I know should be wrong?), but the if else clause might return a "json" which is an any. Thus it's possible errorHandle is returning a legit json, but the tsc compiler thinks it's ok to compile and run. Worse, I didn't even get runtime error while json is returned

Am I missing something?

Second question: what's the best way to deal with "APIError" and "legit APIResponse" in this case? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

There's no error here, this is intended behavior. `any` types do away with all type safety checks (including the return value) and should be used sparingly if at all.

> Worse, I didn't even get runtime error while json is returned

Just as a note, TS doesn't introduce any new runtime behavior (beyond the minimal bit necessary for classes and decorators). The type checking is purely at compile time. You should never expect runtime error handling from TS.

---

Your second question may get more attention by posting it as its own distinct question. Anyway you may want to look into [user defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) and create some that operate on a status field.